# Is `Host` required in HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, get, netcat

The following example shows that `Host:` must be specified. Is this dictated by the HTTP protocol for the GET request or it is just a non-standard feature from http://httpbin.org? Thanks.

```
$ netcat --version 
netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1
Copyright (C) 2002 - 2003  Giovanni Giacobbi

This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

Original idea and design by Avian Research <hobbit@avian.org>,
Written by Giovanni Giacobbi <giovanni@giacobbi.net>.

$ sed 's/$/\r/g' <<EOF | netcat -v httpbin.org 80
GET /get HTTP/1.1
Host:httpbin.org

EOF
httpbin.org [23.23.241.244] 80 (http) open
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Server: meinheld/0.6.1
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 14:41:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: Flask
X-Processed-Time: 0.000858068466187
Content-Length: 157
Via: 1.1 vegur

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "origin": "165.91.87.88", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}

$ sed 's/$/\r/g' <<EOF | netcat -v httpbin.org 80
GET /get HTTP/1.1

EOF
httpbin.org [54.225.64.197] 80 (http) open
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 14:42:33 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/163511/what-is-the-mandatory-information-a-http-request-header-must-contain (Google query that led there: "http request is host name mandatory")

Comment: To be clear: HTTP 1.0 requests don't require it. HTTP 1.1 requests do, and if the request URI does not have a host, then the value should be left blank. (See section 14.23 https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Read. The. Spec. https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.host

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, depends on the Protocol.

In practice if you don't specify a "HOST" what may happen (depending on the web server is configured nginx/apache/hiawatha etc) you may either get content from the default vhost or from the host configured to accept/dispacht request from the IP.

you could test by using:

```
 echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n\n" | nc stackoverflow.com 80
```

Here this may be the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Domain Not Found
Server: Varnish
Retry-After: 0
content-type: text/html
Cache-Control: private, no-cache
connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-hhn1546-HHN
Content-Length: 220
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 07 Apr 2018 20:45:56 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
<title>Fastly error: unknown domain </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Fastly error: unknown domain: . Please check that this domain has been added to a service.</p>
```

And now by adding the host:

```
 echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.0\nHost: stackoverflow.com\n\n" | nc stackoverflow.com 80
```

or using `HTTP/1.1` (which requires to specify a host)

```
echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: stackoverflow.com\n\n" | nc stackoverflow.com 80
```

You will see/get a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
```